# Keeping track of completed migrations in rails when using config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I am familiar with how Rails keeps track of latest migration ran in `schema.rb` with the `:version` param.  However, when using an `development_structure.sql` file instead a ruby `schema.rb` it doesn't seem to keep track of a version number or completed migrations, and so when I run `rake db:setup` it sets up the schema fine, but rails thinks that none of the migrations have been run.

Is there a mechanism to keep track of migrations?  I've contemplated, patching the `:_dump` task to add an `INSERT` for the current migrations in the database.

I am using Rails 3.2.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked down the problem...

Rails ActiveRecord **does** append `INSERT` statements for each up migration at the end of the `structure.sql` file.

The problem wound up being a problem in the [activerecord-postgis-adapter gem](https://github.com/roadtrippers/activerecord-postgis-adapter) which overrides the `db:structure:dump` rake task and **does not** append the said `INSERT` statement.  I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/dazuma/activerecord-postgis-adapter/pull/97) to fix the problem.